# My jquery product slider has a big grey butt

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider, caroufredsel

Sorry about the title because I don't know how to describe this question in just one sentence.

I made a picture to describe this better(this is a picture i took while it was sliding.)

[image]

I'm currently using the caroufredsel slider plugin and its great, but styling it has been a pain in the butt for me.whatI want to do is to make sure the slider doesn't have the weird boarder/grey box any more and the slides ends on the far edge just like where the slider starts in the above picture.

here is the html:

```
div class="list_carousel">
            <ul id="foo2">
                <li>c</li>
                <li>a</li>
                <li>r</li>
                <li>o</li>
                <li>u</li>
                <li>F</li>
                <li>r</li>
                <li>e</li>
                <li>d</li>
                <li>S</li>
                <li>e</li>
                <li>l</li>
                <li> </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <a id="prev2" class="prev" href="#">&lt;</a>
            <a id="next2" class="next" href="#">&gt;</a>
            <div id="pager2" class="pager"></div>
        </div>
```

and here is the css

```
.list_carousel {
            background-color: #ccc;
            margin: 0 0 30px 47.5px;

            height: 280px;
        }
        .list_carousel ul {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            list-style: none;
            display: block;
        }
        .list_carousel li {
            font-size: 40px;
            color: #999;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: #eee;
            border: 5px solid #999;
            width: 180px;
            height: 250px;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 6px;
            display: block;
            float: left;
        }
        .list_carousel.responsive {
            width: auto;
            margin-left: 0;
        }
        .clearfix {
            float: none;
            clear: both;
        }
        .prev {
            float: left;
            margin-left: 10px;
        }
        .next {
            float: right;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }
        .pager {
            float: left;
            width: 300px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .pager a {
            margin: 0 5px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        .pager a.selected {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
        .timer {
            background-color: #999;
            height: 6px;
            width: 0px;
        }
```

javascript:

```
$('#foo2').carouFredSel({
auto: false,
prev: '#prev2',
next: '#next2',
pagination: "#pager2",
mousewheel: true,
swipe: {
    onMouse: true,
    onTouch: true
    }
});
```

Comment: prepare a jsfiddle with your slider. you might also solve your issue while doing that

Comment: @DevZer0 I tried to use jsfiddle but the javascript doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing the .list_carousel to a fixed size.